# Evitar la sobreescritura de variables, SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Estoy trabajando con un archivo CSV. Una de las columnas esta en formato de **string** y quiero convertirla a tipo **float**. He creado una función que me elimina las comas y los simbolos de moneda. Pero el valor, al ser retornado por la función, se sustituye automáticamente directamente en la variable que contiene toda la información del archivo CSV y me arroja una alerta:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Con el código quedará más claro:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

mainPath = 'C:/Users/Marcos/Documents/'
filePath = './resultados.csv'
fullPath = os.path.join(mainPath, filePath)

# Leo el archivo e igualo la columna 2017 a la variable 'parse'
data = pd.read_csv(fullPath, sep = '\t')
parse = data['2017'] # Igualando a data.loc[:,'2017'] sigue apareciendo la alerta
data.head()
```

El primer resultado usando **head** da lo siguiente. Aclaro, que en el ejemplo estoy trabajando con la columna **2017** y quiero convertirla a **float**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora muestro el resultado de la variable **parse**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función que he creado es la siguiente. Lo que hace es comprobar si el caracter es un número o un punto, crea una nueva variable y la añade a un array:

```
def parseFloat(col):
    length = len(col)
    for i in range(length):
        iElement = col[i]
        newElement = ''
        for j in range(len(col[i])) :
            if iElement[j].isdigit():
                newElement += str(iElement[j])
            elif iElement[j] in ['.']:
                newElement += '.'            
        col[i] = newElement
    return col

parsedResult = parseFloat(parse)

print(parsedResult)
```

El resultado del print es el siguiente (con alerta incluida):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no fuese por la alerta el resultado sería el esperado. Pero si consulto la variable original **data** y le hago un **.head()** los valores de la columna **2017** se sustituyen automáticamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero que hay que entender es que **algunas acciones en Pandas que implican seleccionar una sección de los datos originales pueden devolver una vista de los datos y otras devolverán una copia**. Una vista nos permite mostrar un subconjunto de datos como si fueran un DataFrame/Serie distinto, pero en realidad es solo una ilusión, nunca se hace una copia de los datos seleccionados realmente. Es como si usáramos un una plantilla perforada que superponemos sobre la página de un libro y que solo nos deja ver algunas palabras. Esto implica que si tachamos una palabra con la plantilla puesta, tachamos la hoja del libro, es decir, modificar datos mediante la vista causa que estos se modifiquen en el DataFrame que la generó, tal como ocurre en tu caso.

Dicho esto, este warning se lo encuentra tarde  temprano casi todo el que usa Pandas. Vamos a ver mejor un ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [2.2, 3.4, 1.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>> df
A    B
0  1  2.2
1  2  3.4
2  3  1.3
```

Vamos a crear un función estúpida que va a iterar con un `for` sobre la columna y va a ir sumando 2 a cada celda. Digo "estúpida" porque esta operación no tiene sentido hacerla iterando con un ciclo Python ineficiente cuando es simple vectorizarla en Pandas/NumPy, pero es un ejemplo muy simple:

```
def sumar2(columna):
    for i in range(columna.size):
        columna[i] += 2
```

Ahora vamos a ejecutarla pasando la columna A:

> ```
> >>> sumar2(df["A"])
>
> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>    A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame...
> ```

Nuestra querida advertencia...¿Por qué? Pues porque hemos hecho lo que se conoce como **asignación encadenada**:

- Todo empezó en `df["A"]`, lo cual seleccionó la columna `A` del DataFrame, pero Pandas no retornó una copia de los datos, retornó una vista.
- En la función realizamos una asignación (modificamos un valor) mediante `columna[i]`. Dado que el paso anterior retornó una vista, esto es equivalente a `df["A"][i]`... Estamos encadenado dos operaciones de indización sobre la que realizamos una asignación, a esto es a lo que se conoce cono asignación encadenada.

Estas dos operaciones encadenadas **se ejecutan de manera independiente de forma secuencial**, una tras otra. En una primera operación se selecciona una columna de entre las demás del DataFrame usando `__getitem__`, en una segunda se selecciona un índice determinado de dicha columna y se asigna un valor, lo cual se hace mediante el método `__setitem__`. Esta secuencia de indizado, como pronto, hace el código más ineficiente.

**No es sencillo determinar a priori cuando Pandas retorna una vista y cuando una copia**, aunque hay algunas premisas, por ejemplo, las operaciones de indexación sobre un objeto con varios tipos de datos siempre devolverá una copia. Sin embargo, por eficiencia como antes comentamos, sobre un objeto con un solo tipo casi siempre devuelve una vista, lo de "casi siempre" es porque depende del diseño de memoria del objeto. Llegados a este punto cualquiera se hace la pregunta, ¿Por qué Pandas no genera de forma predecible y clara una vista o una copia en cada situación?

Esto se debe a que Pandas usa  NumPy por debajo para representar y operar con los datos a la vez que intenta ofrecer métodos de indexación versátiles. Las vistas vienen heredadas de NumPy, dónde son predecibles principalemtne porque un array en NumPy tiene un solo tipo. Pandas intenta siempre minimizar la memoria y tiempos de procesado a la hora de almacenar el complejo DataFrame con múltiples niveles y tipos usando NumPy por debajo, para ello se han ido creando un conjunto de reglas complejas con el afán de encontrar la mejor estructura  posible de matrices NumPy para representar un conjunto de datos dado. Las secciones de un DataFrame que contienen un solo tipo de dato pueden devolverse como una vista en una sola matriz NumPy, que es una forma altamente eficiente de manejar la operación. Sin embargo las secciones multi-tipo no se pueden almacenar de la misma manera en NumPy y requieren generar una copia con el consiguiente consumo de recursos.

Bien, en este momento sabemos dos cosas:

- Cuando indizamos sobre un DataFrame no sabemos a priori si Pandas retorna una vista o una copia.
- Si encadenamos varias indizaciones mediante `df[...][...][...]` se realizan de forma independiente secuencialmente.

¿Qué tiene esto que ver con la maldita alerta?

Pues, que si una de las operaciones de indizado retorna una vista y no una copia  el resultado puede ser impredecible, dado que los efectos se reflejarán también en el conjunto de datos que generó esa vista. Puede que queramos o no este efecto colateral, pero dada su naturaleza impredecible e inconsistente se genera el Warning para alertar de ello. Puede parecer algo inocente, pero modificar inadvertidamente datos originales cuando no queríamos hacerlo puede ocasionar uno de los peores errores en este mundo,resultados erróneos que pasan totalmente inadvertidos sin excepciones o valores claramente aberrantes...

En tu caso, si querías parsear adecuadamente la columna en el propio DataFrame no hay problema, pero si esto ocurre cuando no es deseado puede ser un desastre con resultados impredecibles e inconstantes.

La solución es aprender a detectar y evitar siempre la asignación encadenada, esta misma operación se puede hacer usando `loc` de la siguiente forma:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [2.2, 3.4, 1.3]}


def sumar2(data, col_name):
    for i in range(data[col_name].size):
        data.loc[i: col_name] += 1


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>> sumar2(df, "A")
>>> df
   A    B
0  2  3.2
1  4  5.4
2  6  4.3
```

Ni rastro del warning, ¿Por qué? Porque al hacer `loc[i: col_name]` permitimos que la operación de indizado y asignación se realice en un solo paso, en una única llamada a `__setitem__`, por lo que evitamos el problema causado por no poder determinar si la primera indización retornará una vista o una copia, este código es predecible por tanto, modifica in-place el valor de la celda.

Si no podemos o queremos hacer lo anterior, podemos crear una copia explícitamente:

```
def sumar2(col):
    new_col = col.copy()
    for i in range(new_col.size):
        new_col[i] += 2
    return new_col


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["A"] = sumar2(df["A"])
```

En ambos casos  indicamos de forma explícita si se van o no a modificar los datos originales, sabiendo exactamente lo que va a ocurrir de forma determinista, si metemos la pata la metemos porque nos equivocamos no porque NumPy/Pandas decida por si mismo en base a reglas confusas si retorna una vista o una copia en un caso dado dependiendo del tipo de datos, memoria disponible o estado de animo... :).

Hay que tener claro el concepto de indizado encadenado, no es equivalente a `df[...][...][...]...`, lo podemos ocasionar también con `loc`, `iloc` u otras operaciones que impliquen selección de datos si se aplican de forma encadenada:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [2.2, 3.4, 1.3]}


def sumar2(columna):
    columna.loc[0:] += 1


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sumar2(df.loc[df.A>1])
```

Los ejemplos están un poco forzados pero espero que sirvan para entender el concepto.

> El warning en mi opinión no debería ignorarse nunca, incluso entendiendo perfectamente su causa y  cuando nos importa un pimiento si el DataFrame original se modifica o no y si esto es inconsistente incluso entre ejecuciones. Como el zen de Python reza, "Explícito mejor que implícito", dado que hay formas como se ha comentado de forzar la modificación in-place o la copia, mejor hacerlo explícito y bien desde un principio que ignorar el warning.

Dicho esto, si quieres convertir la columna en el DataFrame original directamente puedes simplemente hacer:

```
>>> import pandas as pd


>>> data = {"2017": ("1,172.90 €", "53,963.87 €")}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df["2017"] = df["2017"].replace('[\€,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)

>>> df
       2017
0   1172.90
1  53963.87
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y por la última parte de cómo convertir la columna a float. Más claro imposible !!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente, he podido solucionar el error.

Dentro de la función he creado un nuevo DataFrame y después lo he igualado a la columna **2017**

```
def parseFloat(col):
    length = len(col)
    newCol = {}
    newCol['2017'] = []
    for i in range(length):
        iElement = col[i]
        newElement = ''
        for j in range(len(col[i])) :
            if iElement[j].isdigit():
                newElement += str(iElement[j])
            elif iElement[j] in ['.']:
                newElement += '.'            
        newCol['2017'].append(newElement)
    return pd.DataFrame(newCol)

parsedResult = parseFloat(parse)
print(parsedResult)
```

Aún así, si alguien pudiera decirme qué era lo que hacia saltar la alerta se lo agradecería, para evitar futuras complicaciones