# Conocer el contenido de una celda concreta en la última fila de un DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Quiero conocer el valor de que tiene mi columna 'code' en la última fila, puesto que este será un valor que irá incrementando en 1. Se que debe ser muy fácil pero no lo consigo.

Para mostrar la última fila hago

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
print(df[-1:])
```

Pero al querer mostrar solo una columna concreta no lo consigo.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
print(df.loc[[-1:], ['code']])
```

Esta es la última prueba, está fatal pero no termmino de entender el funcionamiento.

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varias posibilidades para obtener el último valor de una columna determinada (`code` en este caso), entre ellas:

- Usando `loc`, selección solo mediante etiqueta:

  ```
  df.loc[df.index[-1], "code"]
  ```
- Usando `iloc`, selección mediante posición, índice entero:

  ```
  df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc("code")]
  ```

  También puedes obtenerlo indexando de forma encadenada junto a indexado directo:

  ```
  df.code.iloc[-1]
  df["code"].iloc[-1]
  df.iloc[-1].code
  df.iloc[-1]["code"]
  ```
- Usando `at`, similar a `loc` pero para un solo valor:

  ```
  df.at[df.index[-1], "code"]
  ```
- Usando `iat`, similar a `iloc` pero para un solo valor:

  ```
  df.iat[-1, df.columns.get_loc("code")]
  ```

  o también:

  ```
  df.code.iat[-1]
  df["code"].iat[-1]
  ```
- Usando indexado/slicing directo obtenemos una `Serie` con un solo elemento:

  ```
  df.code[-1:]
  df["code"][-1:]
  df.code.tail(1)
  df["code"].tail(1)
  ```

Cuando se selecciona de forma encadenada hay que tener mucho cuidado si asignamos un nuevo valor, la llamada [asignación encadenada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/188140/15089).

En los casos de `loc` y `at`, dado que el acceso se hace por etiqueta, no puedes usar `-1` para acceder a la última fila, dado que intentaría acceder a la fila cuyo índice tiene **valor -1, no en posición -1**).

Por otro lado, `at`/`iat` generalmente es la opción más eficiente si solo quieres acceder o asignar un solo valor.