# Obtener texto de cada fila de un csv para insertarlo en una imagen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, pillow

Estoy tratando de crear una serie de imágenes usando una imagen base a la que le inserto un texto determinado procedente de un archivo .csv

Cada imagen generada, con su texto escrito, será guardada de forma independiente como archivo .jpg

El código es este:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import pandas as pd


datos = pd.read_csv('Para_Carnets.csv', sep=";")
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

A = 0
N = 0
for i in range(len(df)):

    # Abre la Imagen
    im = Image.open("Carnet_doble_base.jpg")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im) 
    #Tamaño de la imagen
    W, H = (227,290)        

    #Imprime numero de abonado              
    pA = (datos.loc[[A],["NumeroDeAbonado"]])
    A = A+1
    draw.text((W/2, 103), "Nº Abonado: " + str(pA), fill="white") 

    #Imprime nombre y apellidos
    pN = print (datos.loc[[N],["NombreApellidos"]])
    N = N+1
    draw.text((W/3, H/4), str(pN), fill="yellow")


    #Imprime fecha validez
    #t = (fInicial.get())
    temp = "válido hasta el " + "t"
    font_t = ImageFont.truetype("agency_fb.ttf", 12) 
    draw.text((W/2, 130), str(temp), font=font_t, fill="black") 

    #Graba la imagen
    Nomb_Imagen = str(pA + pN)
    im.save(str(Nomb_Imagen) + ".jpg")
```

Todas las celdas a escribir del archivo .csv tienen datos

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> TypeError: Could not compare [None] with block values

que interpreto como que le faltasen datos al archivo .csv en cuestión. Lo cual no es cierto. ¿Es correcta mi interpretación? ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

---

### Edición 1

Gracias a los comentarios he resuelto el primer error, efectivamente el `print` de `pN = print (datos.loc[[N]` no debería estar. No obstante ahora tengo un nuevo error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/PATINANDO/carnet/LaMaqDeHacerCarnets/solocodigoAceptar.py', wdir='C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/PATINANDO/carnet/LaMaqDeHacerCarnets')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-fe3ad640cfbc>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/PATINANDO/carnet/LaMaqDeHacerCarnets/solocodigoAceptar.py', wdir='C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/PATINANDO/carnet/LaMaqDeHacerCarnets')

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/PATINANDO/carnet/LaMaqDeHacerCarnets/solocodigoAceptar.py", line 44, in <module>
    im.save(str(Nomb_Imagen) + ".jpg")

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1966, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '  NombreApellidos  NumeroDeAbonado\n0             NaN              NaN.jpg'
```

---

### Edición 2

Efectivamente FJSevilla, por ignorancia no salgo de utilizar el DataFrame en vez de utilizar los valores del mismo.

Este es el .csv que estoy utilizando en las pruebas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los nombres de las columnas son: "NumeroDeAbonado" y "NombreApellidos"

Los valores que quiero imprimir en la imagen (dentro de ella) y como nombre de la misma la guardarla son "pA" (cada número de abonado) y "pN" (cada nombre)

Comment: ¿puedes poner el traceback del error completo? Para saber a qué línea se refiere

Comment: Concuerdo con fedorqui. No obstante,  esta línea es un problema: `pN = print (datos.loc[[N],["NombreApellidos"]])`, **`pN` siempre es el retorno de `print`, es decir `None`**. Si quieres imprimir debes hacer `pN = datos.loc[[N],["NombreApellidos"]]` y luego `print(pN)`, pero no asignes a  `pN ` el retorno  de `print`. El error supongo que lo lanza `Nomb_Imagen = pA + pN`, porque `pN` es `None`.

Comment: Algo tienes mal en la forma en que construyes el nombre del fichero en el que pretendes guardar la imagen. Si observas el error, éste se produce porque intentas crear un fichero llamado `'  NombreApellidos  NumeroDeAbonado\n0             NaN              NaN.jpg'`, que contiene retornos de carro (además de que parece estar entero mal), lo que no es permitido por el sistema de archivos de tu operativo.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas y la corrección en la edición de la pregunta. (Pido disculpas por haberlo hecho mal).

Por lo que comentas y tras haber probado varias opciones considero mi código un tanto fracaso, pues muestra el nombre de las columnas del archivo .csv a la vez que imprime el valor de la celda en cuestión y esto es lo que provoca el error. 

Tengo que darle una vuelta más.

Gracias

Comment: Estás obteniendo de forma incorrecta los datos de cada celda del DataFrame  y lo que obtienes no es el valor de la celda sino un DataFrame (además que iteras de una forma muy poco eficiente sobre el mismo). Esto es muy fácil de solucionar, el problema es que creo que o tu csv tiene una estructura incorrecta o lo estás parseando mal como abulafia comentaba. Si pudieras agregar un fragmento de tu csv a la pregunta (copiar y pegar la cabecera y un par de líneas) podríasmos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: No edites la pregunta pues ahora no se entiende el problema si tienes una respuesta colócala abajo por dicha razón te di -1

Comment: Disculpa. Estoy aprendiendo. He reincluido el código que originaba el error del título de la pregunta para que quedase claro.

Comment: @user129500 he editado la pregunta y he añadido la información de ediciones previas. Cuando edites añadiendo información nueva (nuevos errores, cosas nuevas que has probado, ...) es recomendable que lo hagas al final de lo que ya tienes. Esto es importante para no perder el hilo de la pregunta y que los comentarios y respuestas a la misma no queden fuera de contexto. Se que eres nuevo por aquí, ya te iras acostumbrando al sitio, no te preocupes demasiado.

Comment: Dicho esto, he creado una respuesta, las dos soluciones funcionan sin problemas (probadas con el csv que pongo de ejemplo). De no hacerlo el problema está en tu csv (mal formato, problema con separador, caracteres no válidos en celdas, etc). Si tienes algún problema, agrega el contenido del csv como texto, tal y como está en tu archivo (abrir el csv con un editor de texto, copiar y pegar su contenido aquí, no una imagen) o súbelo a algún sitio como GoogleDrive o DropBox y comparte el enlace para que podamos reproducir totalmente el error. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos y en especial @FJSevilla gracias por su amabilidad, dedicación y haber comprendido tan bien mi consulta (y situación).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, para el ejemplo vamos a asumir que tenemos un csv totalmente válido, con `;` como separador e indiferentemente con `\n` o `\r\n` (Windows) como fin de linea. Un ejemplo de ese .csv:

> ```
> NumeroDeAbonado;NombreApellidos
> 1125;Antonio
> 2126;María
> 1453;Laura
> 5454;Fernando
> ```

El primer error, como ya se comentó, era resultado de la línea

```
pN = print (datos.loc[[N],["NombreApellidos"]])
```

lo que causa que `pN` siempre es el retorno de `print`, es decir `None`, lo que causa el error mencionado en la línea `Nomb_Imagen = pA + pN`, porque `pN` es `None`. Se debe eliminar la llamada a  `print`, `pN = datos.loc[[N],["NombreApellidos"]]`.

El segundo error que muestras se debe a que no obtienes correctamente el valor de cada celda del DataFrame, cuando haces `datos.loc[[N],["NombreApellidos"]]` **lo que obtienes es un DataFrame con una única celda, no el objeto `str` que contiene la celda**, lo que causa que en `Nomb_Imagen = str(pA + pN)` intentes concatenar dos DataFrames y no dos cadenas como esperas.  Además, te complicas demasiado para iterar sobre el DataFrame.

Puedes ver una gran variedad de formas de obtener el valor de una celda en esta respuesta a otra pregunta diferente:

- [Conocer el contenido de una celda concreta en la última fila de un DataFrame](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/260440/15089)

No obstante, en este caso, puedes usar `iterrows`, lo que simplifica mucho el tema:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont



W, H = (227, 290) 

datos = pd.read_csv("Para_Carnets.csv", sep=";")

for _, abonado in datos.iterrows():
    im = Image.open("Carnet_doble_base.jpg")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im) 

    num_abon = abonado["NumeroDeAbonado"]
    draw.text((W / 2, 103), f"Nº Abonado: {num_abon}", fill="white") 

    nombre = abonado["NombreApellidos"]
    draw.text((W / 3, H / 4), nombre, fill="yellow")

    fecha_val = "01/01/2020"
    font_t = ImageFont.truetype("agency_fb.ttf", 12) 
    draw.text((W/2, 130), f"Válido hasta el {fecha_val}", font=font_t, fill="black") 

    nombre_imagen = f"{num_abon}_{nombre}.jpg"
    im.save(nombre_imagen)
```

Hay más formas de iterar sobre el DataFrame, incluso se puede usar una función y `DataFrame.apply`, no obstante, si solo usas el DataFrame para cargar el csv, deberías considerar usar en su lugar el módulo `csv` de la biblioteca estándar de Python y no Pandas. Esto es porque con Pandas cargas en memoria todo el archivo lo que es una enorme sobrecarga (generar un nuevo DataFrame, convirtiendo tipos, creando un objeto por cada celda, etc) cuando lo único que necesitas es iterar sobre las filas. Además, iterar sobre un DataFrame es intrínsecamente ineficiente, no está pensado para ello sino para realizar operaciones vectorizadas sobre los datos.

```
import csv
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont



W, H = (227, 290) 

with open("Para_Carnets.csv", newline='') as f:
    for abonado in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=";"):
        im = Image.open("Carnet_doble_base.jpg")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im) 

        num_abon = abonado["NumeroDeAbonado"]
        draw.text((W / 2, 103), f"Nº Abonado: {num_abon}", fill="white") 

        nombre = abonado["NombreApellidos"]
        draw.text((W / 3, H / 4), nombre, fill="yellow")

        fecha_val = "01/01/2020"
        font_t = ImageFont.truetype("agency_fb.ttf", 12) 
        draw.text((W/2, 130), f"Válido hasta el {fecha_val}", font=font_t, fill="black") 

        nombre_imagen = f"{num_abon}_{nombre}.jpg"
        im.save(nombre_imagen)
```

Comment: Efectivamente @FJSevilla esa es la cuestión. En un principio había utilizado 'import csv' pero había tratado mal las listas y siempre imprimía los valores entre corchetes [ ]. Por ello busqué una solución en "pandas". Así es que sin saberlo me has respondido a dos dudas que tenía. Gracias.

Aunque sean cuestiones de un nivel de programación muy básico, explicaciones tan claras como las que acabas de hacer no son frecuentes, por lo que creo que las hace especialmente interesantes. (Sí había leído anteriormente la página del enlace recomendada, pero no supe manejar la información en mi caso).